# Downloading, Re-encoding, and Joining YouTube Videos

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube, video-conversion, mp4box

I've downloaded a set of Youtube Videos that are part of the same episode. Currently I've tried converting them into mp4 using ffmpeg and then joining with MP4Box.

```
for f in *.flv; do ffmpeg -i "$f" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${f%.flv}.mp4"; done
MP4Box -cat part0.mp4 -cat part1.mp4 -cat part2.mp4 -cat part3.mp4 -cat part4.mp4 -new  video.mp4
```

However, upon joining with MP4Box opening the video in VLC does strange things. It seems create a video that has 3 different videos playing at the same time. Upon inspection, the videos have different bitrates and framerates, is this causing the problem?

Therefore, I'd like to re-encode the videos so that they are all the same and then joining them. Or is there a better way of accomplishing what I want?

Edit: I should have mentioned, I'd like to do this on the command line, as I want to semi-automate this process. Thanks!

Edit2: Seems like people are having similar problems as me with MP4Box. Sources:[1](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=160237) and [2](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/306475-joining-serveral-files-with-mp4box-results-in-2-video-streams). Then I tried avidemux, and it will merge them correctly but the audio is accelerated which is also cited [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1356858).

Final Edit and Solution:
I followed the advice in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10610922&postcount=4) and converted the videos to mkv first, and then joined using mkvmerge, which worked great! Thanks!

Comment: It's worth posting that final edition and solution, as an answer and accepting it.

Comment: I didn't even realize you could answer your own question. Thanks and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice [in this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10610922&postcount=4) and converted the videos to mkv first, and then joined using mkvmerge, which worked great! Plus it's faster than the aforementioned software.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give [openshot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) a try? It's a free (as in speech) video editor for Linux.

> OpenShot Video Editor is a free,
>   open-source video editor for Linux
>   licensed under the GPL version 3.0.
>
> OpenShot can take your videos, photos,
>   and music files and help you create
>   the film you have always dreamed of.
>   Easily add sub-titles, transitions,
>   and effects, and then export your film
>   to DVD, YouTube, Vimeo, Xbox 360, and
>   many other common formats.

So if you're using ubuntu for example, it can join the videos for you easily.

Comment: I'm trying to script this up, is there a command line interface? Their documentation seems to be a little lacking.

Comment: When I tried using with my 1080p 60fps recordings it seemed very imprecise, clunky and it crashed. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the bare-bones video editors of most operating systems. In Ubuntu, Pitivi (the most basic of functionality); in Windows, Windows movie maker; in OSX, iMovie. You can open a project, import and join whichever clips you want, and export it to your desired format.

Comment: he said command line in his edit

Comment: Which was made after I answered.

Comment: Yes i'm not blaming you. But it still makes your answer somewhat irrelevant, but I suppose you may as well leave it unless you can add anything in an edit that is better.

Comment: You're right, it is somewhat irrelevant, but I might as well leave it -- don't have anything else to add, and it might help somebody else who doesn't need the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) - it also has CMD interface, but I never used it. However, Avidemux always had good results as I needed it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The ffmpeg faq describes how to join video files. I don't know if this will solve the problem for you, but you may find it useful: [How to join video files](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#TOC27)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ffmpeg concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#concat-3) to concatenate multiple video files.

```
-filter_complex concat=n=%2:a=1
```

For example

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.flv -i vid2.flv -filter_complex concat=n=2:a=1 out.mp4
```

Note that the n parameter specifies the number of video files in this case.